# Travel from Ohare Airport to Delevan WI

Tags: airports, uber

Can I arrange an Uber directly from O'Hare airport ?   If so where do they generally pickup from?

Answer (score 1):

[Yes](https://www.uber.com/global/en/airports/ord/):

> For most requests, you’ll meet your driver upstairs on the Departures level.
>
> Riders requesting Uber Black or SUV, and those in the International Terminal, please meet your driver downstairs on the Arrivals level.

The app will ask you for your location within the airport and will prompt you where to go when you do this.

Keep in mind that this is a considerable distance and [will likely cost $100+](https://www.uber.com/fare-estimate/). You might find it cheaper to get a car service or shuttle, rent a car, take the train part of the way, or use other transport options.